# TwitterStream with Spark streaming returnin Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, twitter-streaming-api

So today I'm trying to execute my first spark streaming script using Java.
For now all I'm trying to do is to get a stream of tweets using the spark streaming Twitter API and to filter it.

After exporting my program to a jar file(simplestream.jar) I did run this command:
spark-submit simplestream.jar

The result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:simplestream/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:639)
at        org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

After some research I found that by switching to jre7 that will fix the problem, but I can't do it since I'm using lambda expressions in my code only supported by version 8 and above:

```
package simplestream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils;

import twitter4j.auth.Authorization;
import twitter4j.auth.AuthorizationFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationContext;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Twitter4J
    // IMPORTANT: adjust your API keys in the twitter4J.properties file
    Configuration twitterConf = ConfigurationContext.getInstance();
    Authorization twitterAuth = AuthorizationFactory.getInstance(twitterConf);

    // Spark
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("Tweets Android")
            .setMaster("local[2]");
    JavaStreamingContext sc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(5000));

    // basic stats on tweets
    String[] filters = { "#Android" };
    TwitterUtils.createStream(sc, twitterAuth, filters)
            .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.getHashtagEntities()))
            .map(h -> h.getText().toLowerCase())
            .filter(h -> !h.equals("android"))
            .countByValue()
            .print();

    sc.start();
    sc.awaitTermination();
}
}
```

I'm using eclipse on cloudera vm, compiler level : 1.7 & JRE : 1.8

Comment: Which java version is set in your Spark nodes?

Comment: This error usually happens when using different incompatible versions of Java. You probably compiled with Java 8, and then running it with Java 7. Or something of that sort.

Comment: i'm using eclipse on cloudera vm, compiler level : 1.7 & JRE : 1.8

Comment: yuval, how can i check that?